# How to get a value from particular cell in WPF 4.0 Datagrid?

Tags: wpf

How to get a value from particular cell in WPF 4.0 Datagrid? Which event will I use for it?

Comment: The answer to `which event will I use for it???` depends on the instance when you want it actually?